# AttributeError at /course/expression-regular-django/ 'ContactCourses' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa0na.png)

I had this problem whem i want do Send local email on my django app...
I'm not realizing it, because I'm accessing the attribute inside the class. Memos when I step {name}, it does not recognize. Thanks Best regards

```
class ContactCourses(forms.Form):

     name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=100)
     email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
     message= forms.CharField(label='Message', widget=forms.Textarea)

    def sendEmail(self, course):
        subject = f'Contacto {course}'
        message= f"Nome: {self.name}, E-mail: {self.email}, {self.message}"
    context = {
        'name': self.cleaned_data['name'],
        'email': self.cleaned_data['email'],
        'message': self.changed_data['message']
    }

    message= message% context
    send_mail(subject,
              message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
              [settings.CONTACT_EMAIL])

class Courses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho')
    descricao = models.TextField('Descrição Simples', blank=True)
    sobre = models.TextField('Sobre o Curso', blank = True)
    data_inicio = models.DateField('Data de início',
    null = True, blank = True)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_courses', verbose_name='Imagem', null=True, blank=True
)
```

Comment: add your `ContactoCursos` model

Comment: My model is Courses

Comment: But your error says you try to save inContactCourses. Can you add the related code to save data after submitting form?

Comment: i dont save... only i testing